# How to show this inequality with matrix norms?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, normed-spaces

> Let $A$ be invertible and $M$ of the same size as $A$. Show that if $$\frac{\|M\|}{\|A^{-1}\|}\le c \le \frac{1}{2}$$ then $A+M$ is invertible and $$\frac{\|(A+M)^{-1} - A^{-1} \|}{\|A^{-1}\|}\le 2c.$$

I have shown that $A+M$ is invertible by using

> If $\|T\| < 1$ then $(I-T)$ is invertible.

Now does one show the inequality?